# com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have a problem when i try to use DropWizard and Views.

```
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class com.linker.views.TicketView, and Java type class com.linker.views.TicketView, and MIME media type text/html was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
```

This is how i call the function that is suppose to return my view

```
  @GET
  @Path("/list")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public TicketView listTickets() {
    return new TicketView();
  }
```

and here is a simple version of my TicketView class

```
public class TicketView extends View {
  public TicketView(){
    super("test.ftl");
  }
}
```

and lastly here is my maven dependency that is affected (i think)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? or atleast help me to get on the right path.

Comment: Did you [add the `ViewBundle` to the `Bootstrap`](http://dropwizard.io/manual/views.html)?

Comment: I was just going to write that i found the solution :p I made a booboo. I forgot to add that bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was the following. As Peeskillet mentioned above. i forgot to add `viewbundle` on my application class

```
  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<SupportServerConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new ViewBundle());
  }
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your Jersey application configuration, you should register special feature to enable HTML body writer.
If you have java base config it could look similar to:

```
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestApplication() {
        packages("lv.autentica");

        // registering JSON support
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how exactly feature for Html support is named.
And you should check if you really need to return an HTML as a response. This looks quite strange when using Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the message body writer class for your com.linker.views.TicketView class, like this:

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public TicketViewWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<TicketView> {

 @Override
 public boolean isWriteable(
  final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType
) {
    return (
        mediaType.isCompatible(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
    ) && TicketView.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
  }

@Override
public long getSize(
    final TicketView view, final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations,
    final MediaType mediaType
  ) {

    return -1;
   }

@Override
public void writeTo(
    final TicketView view, final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations,
    final MediaType mediaType, final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, final OutputStream entityStream
) throws IOException {
    try {
        // your logic here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log exception
    }
  }
}
```

This is only the example, it's up to you to decide what to do in the "writeTo" method. You will maybe also have to implement the message body reader class as well. Have a look at [this link!](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)

Comment: The wierd thing is that i have done two servers with Dropwizard. I used hibernate for the first one. Now im trying with jdbc. But i never had to do something like this when i used hibernate. Could it be that i forgot to import something that helps me out with this?

Comment: I think Hibernate's approach to persist entities in a db is a bit different. Maybe that is why Hibernate did not throw the above exception. And why do you need the response to be an html?